# Unable to show spinner or loading... in Angular 6 while using *ngIf

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have 4 buttons like tabs, when I click on first button I have to render first component, if click on second button then second component like so..

Now my problem is when I am switching/clicking one button to another components takes too much time to render **DOM** so that I want to display ***"Loading....."***.

Comment: add any third party loader. it will work

Comment: is your component waiting  for retrieving some data from server then you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-http-loader

Comment: By unable to show spinner or loading what do you mean? They don't appear at all or what happens? Also if you can add some code it will be helpful.

Comment: you have to use mat-spinner for show loading and use this in ngIf is like: *ngIf="data; else loading_template".

Answer (score 1):

If you just wish to show ***Loading ...***, then modify the `index.html` to look like this:

```
<app-root>
  Loading ...
</app-root>
```

If you want a pure CSS Loader, modify the `index.html` to look like this:

```
<body>
   <app-root>
     <div class="loader">Loading ...</div>
   </app-root>
</body>
```

And now animate the `.loader` class as per your preference. You can play with the Plunker that I have created here: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/Ox5uJGpDSkMYQ9Fp

Answer (score 0):

If every component has it's own route then you can subscribe to Router.

In app.component.ts

```
import { Router, Event as RouterEvent, NavigationStart, NavigationEnd, NavigationCancel, NavigationError } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router) {
        this.router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
            this.navigationInterceptor(event)
        });
}

navigationInterceptor(event: RouterEvent): void {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
            this.loading = true
        }
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            this.loading = false
        }

        // Set loading state to false in both of the below events to hide the spinner in case a request fails
        if (event instanceof NavigationCancel) {
            this.loading = false
        }
        if (event instanceof NavigationError) {
            this.loading = false
        }
    }
```

In app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<spinner-component [spinnerShow]="loading_data"></spinner-component>
```

Spinner.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'spinner-component',
  templateUrl: './spinner.component.html',
 styleUrls: ["./spinner.component.scss"]
})

export class SpinnerComponent {
    @Input() spinnerShow: boolean;
}
```

Spinner.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="spinnerShow" class="sc-background"></div>
<div *ngIf="spinnerShow" [ngClass]="{'sc-default-spinner' : ref.children.length == 0 }"  class="logo sc-center">
<div #ref><ng-content></ng-content></div></div>
```

Spinner.component.scss

```
.sc-background{
 content : "";
 z-index: 1004;
 position: absolute;
 top:-10%;
 right:0;
 left:0;
 bottom: 0;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}
.logo {
    background: url("./../../../../assets/images/sprite/template.png") 0px 0px;
    width:30px;
}
.sc-center{
top: 50vh;
margin: auto;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 1005;

}
```

Comment: could you please show me your component spinner-component?

Comment: added spinner component.